# Dual delivery Google Apps and Postifx (server reject mail from my domain on google)

Tags: postfix, smtp, g-suite

This is the scenario:

I have a server with Postfix and some domains, and now, one of this domains want to use Gmail Google Apps only in a couple of accounts.

The end-user configure the domain with Google MX registrys, configure the mail accounts in Google and the other accounts points to my server.

I've configured the external accounts with transport to the MX.

When I send an email for example, from Hotmail, if the account is configured in Google Apps, google keep the mail, and if the account is in my server, then google transport the email to my server.

When internal accounts from my server send mails, I can decide what I do with it and transport to local account or to google.

The problem is:

When the accounts in Google Apps with my client domain try to send mails to same domain accounts, but in my server, my postfix reject this emails with the next message:

```
30 14:00:28 ***** postfix/smtpd[13400]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-la0-f43.google.com[209.85.215.43]: 553 5.7.1 <client-on-google@domain.com>: Sender address rejected: not logged in; from=<client-on-google@domain.com> to=<client-on-my-server@domain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-la0-f43.google.com>
```

This is normal, but... how I can permit relay from google to this users/domain only?

I call to Google Apps support, and they say they don't permit smtp auth on my server to send this mails.

Another solution?

Comment: You probably have something mis-configured on postfix, postfix won't normally reject mail to local users, unless you give it specific reasons to do so.  Posting your main.cf might help, as would the logs from your postfix server where postfix says why it rejected the message.

Comment: Hi,I think this is the normal postfix process.
If i recieve  a mail from another server who claim be a domain.com, but i have configured this domain in the server, Postfix reject this, beacuse he don't send the mail.
I'm running Ubuntu and ISPConfig with ClamAV, Postfix and Dovecot.

Comment: While I believe I understood what you are asking for, it is going to be very hard to diagnose your problem without knowing how you configured postfix, and also what the postfix server says when it rejects mail from google apps.

Comment: Thanks Nick.
I think this is easier, at least is than i want to believe :D
Just i want to know the way to permit only a couple of users like "mynetworks" do for all the users.
Postfix must do that, or not?

Comment: What I am saying is that postfix should not reject messages from outside to users on the postfix machine. If it is, there are a few possibilities. 1. misconfiguration (does the postfix server know that it is responsible for that domain?) 2. the server on the other side is doing something wrong (google tends not to do that).

Comment: Ok, i know.
But the server is rejecting the mail because, my server have this domain.
Google host the domain client.com and my server also host the domain client.com, right?
When google try to send like user1(at)client(dot)com to user2(at)client(dot)com on my server, my postfix rejects it.
I think Postfix do that by default (my work pal configure the server).

Sorry if i don't understand you.

Very thanks you Nick!
Regards

Comment: If i send an email from the Google Apps domain client-on-google@domain.com to client-on-my-server@domain.com it's bounced, but if i send to another domain on my server, example, client-on-my-server@domainB.com. it's arrived correctly.
Any idea?
I see if i can post the main.cf here.
Thanks you.
Regards.

Comment: I think if you post your main.cf, you'll be able to get more help. Is your primary domain a virtual domain?

Comment: Currently, this is my main.cf:
http://pastebin.com/PCfBQadV

Thanks you Nick!!

Comment: So, is domain.com configured in `virtual_mailbox_domains`? Because it doesn't seem to be `mydestination`..

Answer (score 1):

I solve it with Postfix white list managed by ISPConfig:

Mail -> Global filters -> Postfix Whitelist 
Just add a new mail with the filter type "Sender".

This permit all the traffic from the mail/domain specified.