# Selective "mynetworks" per domain on Postfix

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

My question is related with this: [Dual delivery Google Apps and Postifx (server reject mail from my domain on google)](https://serverfault.com/questions/564644/dual-delivery-google-apps-and-postifx-server-reject-mail-from-my-domain-on-goog)

Well, i've some servers with Ubuntu running an ISPconfig with Postfix.

My question is:
Is possible do a selective mynetworks policy per domain/user on postfix?
For example, only apply some IP's permitted for a domain, but no for all others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do something similar with the postfix [Restriction Classes](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html), in fact, their examples speak specifically to the necessity to implement different types of restrictions for different users.

As the [access](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) tables allow, you could create a per user access table (or a group), and allow mail from them, from specific IPs.

Comment: Thanks you Nick for your answer, the link is very useful. 

But now, i don't understand some things of the link. 
Ok, i need a create a class, some like: 

`/etc/postfix/main.cf: 

smtpd_restriction_classes = restrictive, permissive
restrictive = -here policies to deny-
permissive = permit


    smtpd_sender_restrictions = 
        permit_mynetworks
        reject_unauth_destination
        check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_access`

Comment: And then, i need to create a hash file with the list of domains, users,...

`/etc/postfix/recipient_access:
    joe@my.domain       permissive
    jane@my.domain      restrictive`

By default, if i don't put a user in this list, would take the restrictive policy, right?
But, how i can apply this to mynetworks policy?
How i must put some IP's on a class, and other IP's or IP range in other class?

Thanks you Nick.

Comment: Have a look at the access table, if it doesn't find a match, it tends to use the default. You shouldn't need to specify a specific mynetworks type of class, just make email to those users hosted on the google apps part of the permissive class, then they should be accepted..

Comment: Ok thanks you.
But, then i cannot specify the IP of origin for every mail account, right?
Well, this is useful for my purposes.
Thanks you Nick!

Comment: In theory, if you wanted to spend the time, you probably could specify the allowed IP for every email, but I think the administrative burden would be too heavy to be realistic. A permissive acceptance policy should be almost as effective..

Comment: Ok.
Thanks you very much Nick.
This is my first time asking in ServerFault, but with users like you,  this is a great platform!

Answer (score 0):

Well, now i found how to do that in ISPConfig.

Mail -> Global filters -> Postfix Whitelist
Just add a new mail with the filter type "Sender".

This permit all the traffic from the mail/domain specified.

Comment: Good job on the research :)

Comment: Thanks Nick.
It's not perfect, i can't specify the IP from incoming traffic, but this works for me and my purposes.

Thanks you very much Nick, for your help during my questions :D